# Ag - grid isEditable for row editing depends on a button value outside of ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

so basically i have this checkbox button , when multiple will be clicked their values gets updated in each row .
Alright now i have this edit button outside of ag grid that will determine now i can edit those selected rows.
I know i can update col defs. or use valueParam from that checkbox to isEditable call back function, But I require an variable value that's outside of ag-grid.
Please help !!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
So we can use a external variable via providing context property in aggrid grid options .


  enableEdit(table:any){
        if(table === 'tableOne'){
          this.editTable1 = !this.editTable1;
          this.grid1.gridOptions.context= {
            allowEdit: this.editTable1,
          }
        }else{
          this.editTable2 = !this.editTable2;
          this.grid1.gridOptions.context= {
            allowEdit: this.editTable2,
          }
        }
        
      }
    
With col defs as =>


  {headerName: 'Status',editable:(param)=>{return allowCagRefEdit(param)}, field: 'status', sortable: true, filter: true, lockVisible: true, lockPosition: true, filterParams: { newRowsAction: 'keep'}},

where allowCagRefEdit is a function =>

function allowCagRefEdit(params){
  console.log("params value ***",params);[enter link description here][1]
  let checkkBoxSelected = false;
  if(params.data && params.data.cagRefManualCheck){
    checkkBoxSelected = true;
  }else{
    checkkBoxSelected = false;
  }
  if(params.context && params.context.allowEdit && checkkBoxSelected){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).